# template is rendered outside layout

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a simple layout created using bootstrap 3 and have a row with a handlebar template declared like this:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">

        {{#link-to 'new'}}New Entry{{/link-to}}

    </script>
    </div>

</div>
```

When the page is rendered, the link is created outside the `container` div:

[image: container]

Am I doing something wrong? The link is supposed to be generated between the horizontal lines. Also when I open up the Ember Inspector, the application template is shown as follows:

---

[image: View from ember inspector]

I have been trying to find solutions for this but it seems no one else has encountered this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you didn't specify the root element for the Ember App? If you didn't it assumes the root element to be the body. In your app.js file you could specify something like this:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '.col-xs-12'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're likely missing an `{{outlet}}` in one of your resource templates. If you don't include one explicitly, Ember will just append to the bottom of the page (outside of your `container` div).